# Array throws error when called

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am creating an array from the values of a range, but when trying to get the values from the array, an error comes up. The code is:

```
Dim nombre() As Variant 'Declares the array
Dim arreglo As Long 'Declares the length of the array

fin = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'Gets the last column with data
nombre = Range("B3:B" & fin).Value 'Fills the array with the values within the range
arreglo = Application.CountA(nombre) 'Gets the length of the array, in this case, 52

MsgBox nombre(1) 'This throws an error
```

I think the problem arises when filling the arrange with values.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `MsgBox nombre(1,1)` it is a two dimensional array with only one column.

Comment: What error code is? In which line your code stops? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well to @DavidG.'s point, your question does indeed fail to specify exactly what the error is. Yes, you show what statement is throwing the error, but answerers need to copy your code and run it in order to find out what the exact error message is. Wouldn't it be easier to include it in the question?

Comment: Also I don't understand your question to @ScottCraner. FWIW a `Variant` can very well hold an array of variants, so you do `Dim foo As Variant` and it holds whatever you put in it - but it works regardless of whether you declare it `foo As Variant` or `foo() As Variant`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, Scott wrote another comment, but apparently he deleted it.

Comment: No that was not me but someone else.  My only message before this was the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Unless a `Range` contains exactly 1 cell, `Range.Value` is always a 2D `Variant` array. If only 1 cell is involved, then the `Variant` will hold that value. So unless you *know* you're dealing with more than a single cell, you can't assume you'll be getting an array all the time.

You'll never get a 1D array directly from a straightforward `Range.Value` call.

You can use the `IsArray` function to determine if you're looking at an array or a single value:

```
Dim nombre As Variant ' don't declare as an array: let the variant hold an array instead
nombre = myRange.Value

If IsArray(nombre) Then
    'nombre is a 2D array
    If Not IsError(nombre(1, 1)) Then MsgBox nombre(1, 1)
Else
    'nombre contains a single value - possibly an error that can't be coerced into a String
    If Not IsError(nombre) Then MsgBox nombre
End If
```